# Defining components as an object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a tutorial ([Serverless-Stack](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/add-the-session-to-the-state.html)) and I am a bit confused by the following code snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default ({ component: C, props: cProps, ...rest }) =>
  <Route {...rest} render={props => <C {...props} {...cProps} />} />;
```

The confusing part is how the props are defined. Most examples I see take `props` as a single parameter, like `export default (props) => ...`, however this is defined as an object.

My understanding is that in JavaScript regular objects are used by calling the key of the object like below:

```
let bar = 'baz';
let myObj = {foo: bar};
console.log(myObj['foo']);
```

My question is: How does the snippet from the tutorial retrieve the props by the values instead of the key? Shouldn't it be `<component ...>` instead of `<C ...>`?

Is there a technical name for defining props like this that I can search to learn more about how it works?

Comment: the parameter passed is expected to be an object so you can use what is called [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to extract some of its properties to [variables with different  names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not values. When destructuring an object, you can rename the variable with that syntax.

```js
({ key0: renamedKey0 }) => ...
```

You can read more about it in the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the section "Assigning to new variable names".

Answer (score 1):

Just try to breakdown the steps for you to visualize what happened

The below code

```
export default ({ component: C, props: cProps, ...rest }) => {
    //...
};
```

Was translated from much longer form as below

```
export default (parameterObject) => {
  let C = parameterObject.component;
  let cProps = parameterObject.cProps;
  //...
};
```

Which then transform shorter into below version

```
export default ({component, cProps}) => {
  let C = component;
  let cProps = cProps;
  //...
};
```

And ultimately transform to the code you posted

```
export default ({ component: C, props: cProps, ...rest }) => {
//...
};
```